Filtering Instruction Data for Revoke Authority Events in Solana Blockchain using logsSubscribe
I'm working with the Solana blockchain and need to track specific events: 'Revoke Mint Authority' and 'Revoke Freeze Authority'. Currently, I'm using the logsSubscribe method in conjunction with webhooks.
I successfully filtered the logs to capture activities associated with the Token Program. However, I'm struggling to filter the instruction data further to differentiate between the types of authorities being revoked. With logsSubscribe, I receive the Token Program instructions, but the necessary details within the instruction data (specifically the authority type involved) are not provided. How can I refine my method to capture and identify these specific authority types within the instruction data? Any guidance or recommendations for approaches to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
This is the scope of my code:
 subscribe_message = {
                    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                    "id": 1,
                    "method": "logsSubscribe",
                    "params": [
                        {"mentions": ["TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"]},
                        {"commitment": "finalized"}
                    ]
                }
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(subscribe_message))


The logsSubscribe endpoint will only tell you when the SetAuthority instruction is called, but won't give any other information unfortunately.
Here's the only log from it: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/d1c03cc6164ebdeebef19190de28b7a71f4e4cb6/token/program/src/processor.rs#L903
You can go one step further, and anytime you see that log, fetch the transaction using getTransaction with jsonParsed encoding, and see if the newAuthority is being set to null. More info about getTranasction at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction
